# android autocomplete only show word match first letter

Tags: android, autocomplete

I'm new to android, now trying to implement autocomplete, my code is as follows

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Logger.getLogger("text").info(textView.getText().toString());
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView.setThreshold(1);
```

where`COUNTRIES` is a list of words like `canada, america`, when i type `c`, the dropdown list only have word `canada` in it, how can i change the code so that word `america` can also show? Thanks

Comment: Does typing `a` help?

Comment: @Onik yes, it only shows the word that matches with the first letter, if the character is in the middle of the word, it'll not work

Comment: Actually that's the point of `AutoCompleteTextView` that autocompletes a word you get to type. There is nothing "auto" in completing `c` with `america`. If you just don't have enough to drop down, simply add several countries with `a` and `c` etc to the COUNTRIES array.